# S3 cross account Data transfer

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3

Looking into sharing data from our S3 bucket to our external partner. Going to setup a AWS Role in our VPC and share that with our external partner. Their access from their system would assume the AWS role created in our account and access the bucket. The data in our S3 bucket is encrypted @rest...

Say if the external vendor after assumption of the role...copies the data from our S3 bucket to their staging environment...how to ensure that the data in Transit will also be encrypted?

Our S3 data is using the defaule SSE-S3 AES256 encryption.

Answer (score 1):

You should do a couple of things here:

1. use [cross-account roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html) to allow them to get temporary credentials
2. use an S3 bucket policy that blocks access over insecure channels using aws:SecureTransport (see below)

Note: this will not stop them doing a couple of things that you probably want to avoid:

1. retrieving your data from outside the AWS region, leading to egress charges for you
2. copying the data elsewhere in an insecure way, *after* they download it

Example S3 bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "id1234",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "sid1234",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: i will try  the above. But, is there client side encryption that could be enabled for the s3 bucket...that would necessitate the data to be decrypted at the receiving end by  using a master-key. This way data could be sent in a non secured channels as well....but the data will be encrypted in transit.

Comment: Well, clearly you could implement whatever encryption you like *before* uploading to S3 and *after* downloading from S3, but also take a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingClientSideEncryption.html

Comment: @MarkChimail `aws:SecureTransport` simply means *HTTPS*.  S3 only communicates using that, or HTTP, which is what this policy would block.